# Is it possible to replicate OpenLDAP from FreeIPA?

Tags: openldap, freeipa

Has anyone tried or even succeeded with having an OpenLDAP server (could be slave replication) to a FreeIPA server?

I have been trying with [osixia's Docker OpenLDAP](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap) but replication never seems to grab a hold not sure if the schema is too far off or what.

Comment: So do you want to bring data from OpenLDAP to FreeIPA? Honestly this seems like a misunderstanding on your side of what each package does: OpenLDAP is a directory protocol while FreeIPA is effectively an IAM (Identity Access Management) system from what I am reading. An IAM system uses various data sources to then assign entitlements and accounts basic on role criteria.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: FreeIPA is its own data source (like MS AD) and does include an LDAP server (389-ds) as its core, so replicating *just* the LDAP database may be possible in theory... but e.g. 389ds has an ACL system completely incompatible with OpenLDAP's, so it wouldn't work well at all.

Comment: Hello Giacomo no I don't want to bring data from openldap to freeipa. I want to go the other way so that freeipa feeds openlap in another location that does not need dns and all the other tools.

Comment: thank you user1686 that is what I fear. I may waste a few more days on it but thank you for confirming some of my ideas.

Comment: If you really want get it to work at least _somewhat,_ it would be best if you showed what you currently have (i.e. the attempted config, the results and/or errors).